# DevExpress MVC ClientSideEvents hides the grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm working on a DevExpress MVC GridView and everything is just fine until I put the following setting:

```
settings.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "SelectionChanged";
```

After this, the grid is "invisible"

When I check the code with Inspect element, I can see the code and when I go over the blocks with the mouse, the elements are highlighted (but not shown) see --> http://prntscr.com/5olbxp

I also wrote the function in the script section:

```
<script>
   function SelectionChanged(s,e) {
     ...
   }
</script>
```

I have no idea why the grid disappears :/

Comment: Is the script defined in the main view or the GridView's partial view? I see that you have errors in Console. Open it to check what errors you are getting.

Comment: @GoshaFighten I forgot to check the errors :/ This is the problem:
http://prntscr.com/5ozlr3 - I have the function in the javascript code at the bottom of the main View (where the grid's partial is invoked from)

Comment: I wrote the function inline `settings.ClientSideEvents.SelectionChanged = "function(s,e){alert('ok');}";` and it works. If we can't find another solution, I will work like this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should be defined before its using by the GridView. Move it at the top of your main view or before rendering the GridView's partial view.